# Display specific field from array list in spinner

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show only one field in spinner from arraylist.

I used to overide toString in model class like this.

```
data class University(
        @SerializedName("university") val university: String,
        @SerializedName("abbr") val abbr: String,
        @SerializedName("university_id") val university_id: String) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$abbr - $university"
    }
}
```

And used it like this in activity

```
        viewModel.getUniversities().observe(
                this,
                Observer { universities ->
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<University>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, universities)
                    universitySpinner.adapter = adapter

                    universitySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {

                        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                            universityId = universities!![position].university_id.toString()
                        }

                        override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {

                        }
                    }
                }
        )
```

This returns one string as I intended.

Now I have similar problem but now my model class is generated  so I cant do override toString but I would like to display only one field(University) in spinner. So what should I do in activity?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Kotlin, you can use an extension function on your class to keep the same syntax as before. Supposing your generated class is called `UniversityGenerated`, the extension function would look like that:

```
fun UniversityGenerated.toString(): String {
    return "${this.abbr} - ${this.university}"
}
```

with `abbr` and `university` still being publicly accessible. You can read more in the official documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/extension-functionsproperties.html).